# Android WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL first page load is a mess. How to fix it?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I use WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL for loading my help page from internal resources of my application.

I have help.html and a few images located in the assets directory. The page loads and shows with images, but the text around image is a mess. It did not show on the right side of the image, instead the image overlaps the text.

This happens only on first loading of the page. If I close the WebView and open it again, then everything is fine.
It seems that at first loading WebView spends some time for loading images and does not reformat page after that. On the second attempt images are cached and displayed together with text and properly formatted.

**What is the solution for this problem?**

**Did anyone face this problem too?**

Here is my code:

```
    app.setContentView(R.layout.help);
    final WebView web = (WebView) app.findViewById(R.id.helpWebView);
    web.setBackgroundColor(0);
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", helpHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Web page is inside the helpHtml string with the code:

```
<html><head></head><body><img src="html/flddesc.png" align="left"/>this should be my long long text...</body></html>
```

P.S: html/flddesc.png is a PNG8 image 180x200 ~20kb of size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
```

Comment: Thank you. loadURL works correctly. So loadDataWithBaseURL has incomplete or buggy realization.

Comment: I dont think so. It is meant for different purpose. Check its documentation here, you will understand: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I read this page before writing this post. There is no word about difference between loading with loadURL or baseURL that connected to my problem. Both can load local data, one from url the other from string, but it should not affect what the user sees on the screen. And I also think that if the page is displayed then it should be displayed properly or not displayed at all.

Comment: @pKs Using the `file:///` notation to load the html file from the disk.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Then what's going to work. Actualy I had a similar problem yesterday and I used `loadwithbaseurl("http://bar",html,"UTF-8","");` to get my html content rendered properly. is this what you want to say.

Comment: @pKs Probably... I'm not sure what the solution is. I just know (from other unresolved StackOverflow questions that I've seen) that using `file:///` won't work.

Comment: @AlexLockwood I don't know if, its a hack or something but check my answer below that worked when nothing did.